# pgrep only current user

Tags: ps

I was wondering what the arguments were for `pgrep` to make it act only on the current user. `-u` makes me provide names, I don't know the name of the current user, I just know that I need current user only.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a UID *or* a name, as you can see in `man pgrep`:

```
   -u euid,...
          Only match processes whose effective user ID is listed.  Either the
          numerical or symbolical value may be used.

   -U uid,...
          Only match processes whose real user ID is listed.  Either the 
          numerical or symbolical value may be used.
```

If you don't know either, just use command substitution:

```
pgrep -u "$(whoami)"
```

Comment: Ah that whomai thing is what I have to do. Thank you!! :) So by default, `pgrep` does all users huh?

Comment: `${UID}` should do, otherwise `"${USER}"`.